# forEach prints only last value, the typical closure issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I tried using this using the approach as how you typically solve any closure issues but apparently this is not working for me. I tried changing it to `let`, `const` or even arrow functions but the code always print the last array element.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```js
var data = [{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "phone": "31227-5325"
}, {
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Campbell",
  "phone": "123123-5325"
}];

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('loaded....');
  data.forEach(function(elem, index) {

    let p = index;
    document.querySelector('#fname').innerHTML = '<td>' + data[p].first_name + '</td>';
    document.querySelector('#lname').innerHTML = '<td>' + data[p].last_name + '</td>';
    document.querySelector('#phone').innerHTML = '<td>' + data[p].phone + '</td>';

  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td id="fname"></td>
    <td id="lname"></td>
    <td id="phone"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/gasegeqila/1/edit?js,output

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With that said, your problem is because you're setting the value of each element in the loop, so only the values set in the last iteration are visible. You instead need to *create* a new row in the loop, and set the values in there

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your logic, it's your output, it's writing to the same HTML elements and overwriting your previously inserted data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i added the relevant code.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you're setting the value of the same elements in the loop, so only the values set in the last iteration are visible.

You instead need to create a new row in the loop and set the values in there, like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "phone": "31227-5325"
}, {
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Campbell",
  "phone": "123123-5325"
}];

window.onload = function() {
  var tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
  
  data.forEach(function(elem, index) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${data[index].first_name}</td><td>${data[index].last_name}</td><td>${data[index].phone}</td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

One way is to create rows and cells separately like that:

```
var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);

var cl1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cl2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cl3 = row.insertCell(2);

cl1.innerHTML = data[i].first_name;
cl2.innerHTML = data[i].last_name;
cl3.innerHTML = data[i].phone;
```

Working example: **https://jsfiddle.net/dkppcdtz/1/**

Comment: I dont want to append, I want to insert a new row for each value

Answer (score 0):

> **the code always print the last array element?**

From [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) 
>   which must be unique in the whole document.

From your script :

```
document.querySelector('#fname').innerHTML = ...;
document.querySelector('#lname').innerHTML = ...;
document.querySelector('#phone'). = .....
```

You always replacing your data with new one.So,there is last element is getting updated.

You can loop like this,

```
var table = document.querySelector('.table.table-border');

data.forEach(function(elem, index) {

    let p = index;
    let newRowHtml = '<tr><td>' + data[p].first_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data[p].last_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data[p].phone + '</td></tr>';


    table.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newRowHtml);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to create your row string and then add the generated string to your table body.

```js
var data = [{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "phone": "31227-5325"
}, {
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Campbell",
  "phone": "123123-5325"
}];

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('loaded....');
  var row = data.reduce(function(str, elem, index) {
    let p = index;
    str += '<tr><td>' + data[p].first_name + '</td><td>' + data[p].last_name + '</td><td>' + data[p].phone + '</td></tr>';
    return str;
  }, '');
  document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML = row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-border">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tr1">
  </tbody>

</table>
```